# Batch print attachments in thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

When I receive emails, I put in a folder each month, that on the month end i need to print all the attachments (pdf).

As sometimes there are about 20-100 emails at a time. Is there a way of selecting all the attachments only to print using Mozilla Thunderbird.